# Agrupar dados relacionado a uma coluna

Tags: php, tabela-html

Estou com problema em agrupar horários por data.

Tenho uma tabela em html que é populada a partir de uma consulta sql. A ideia seria listar em uma coluna a data e na outra coluna todos os horários referente aquela data sem ter que pular linha como na foto que postei no final. O que poderia ser feito?

**Código:**

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>  
      <tr>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Marcações</th>          
      </tr>
  </thead>   
<?php

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($db, $con);

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT dia, hora FROM marcacoes");
    while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    $tabela ='<tbody>'; 
    $tabela .='<tr>';
    $tabela .='<td>'.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($exibe['dia'])).'</td>'; 
    $tabela .='<td>'.$exibe['hora'].'</td>';
    $tabela .='</tr>';
    $tabela .='</tbody>';

    echo $tabela;

    }   
?>
```

**Exemplo do problema:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo em MySQL seria o GROUP_CONCAT que concatena uma coluna, com valor em N linhas em uma só coluna e uma linha, desde que utilizada cláusula GROUP BY nas demais colunas não agrupadoras, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT data, GROUP_CONCAT(hora) As horarios FROM `marcacoes` GROUP BY data;
```

Neste caso você recuperaria os valores das colunas 'data' e 'horarios' no seu código para exibir a informação retornada pelo SELECT.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara deu certo!! aí no caso pra mim exibir essa consulta?

Comment: Para exibir é uma query normal, você deve nomear o GROUP_CONCAT com algum alias para facilitar a recuperação de valores. Vou editar minha resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: Perfeito!! Valeu Bruno pela resposta me ajudou muito!